# Multiple Kendo Grids in a Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm looping through my Model in a Razor View and wanted to display multiple Kendo Grids. However I'm getting all empty grids even though the Item_Read is being executed when the loop happens.

Any ideas?

Source:

```
@foreach (var itemM in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => itemM.id)
            </td>
            <td>

               @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeOtherModel>()
                .Name("KendoGrid" + itemM.id)
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.title);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.details);
                })
                .AutoBind(true)
                 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                 .Ajax()
                 .Model(model =>
                 {
                     model.Id(p => p.itemId);
                     model.Field(p => p.itemId).Editable(false);
                 })
                 .Read(read => read.Action("Item_Read", "Controller", new { id = itemM.id }))
             )
            )
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: First step is to use a debugger in the browser, Kendo Grid is all JavaScript (the MVC Wrapper you use just builds HTML/JavaScript for you). See if any errors are happening, make sure you can reference each grid, check their DataSource property, see if there's any data, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my ViewModel, one of the properties was null.